# Read M3U(playlist) file in java

Tags: java

Does anyone know of a java library that would allow me to read m3u files to get
the file name and its absolute path as an array ... ?

Clarification: I would like my java program to be able to parse a winamp playlist
file (.M3U) to get the name+path of the mp3 files in the playlist

Comment: I've no idea what you ask. What does 'get the file name and its absolute path as an array' exactly mean? Maybe you can show some pseudo code?

Comment: Why not just read the contents of the .m3u file?
get the lines array and prepend to each line the directory of the .m3u file.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search yields [`Lizzy`](http://lizzy.sourceforge.net/), which seems to do [what you want](http://lizzy.sourceforge.net/docs/javadoc/christophedelory/playlist/m3u/M3U.html#toPlaylist%28%29).

Comment: Can not recommend Lizzy at this stage. Unit Tests are basically non-existant, the project is not maintained and buried in Sourceforge. Plus there is hard ffmpeg dependency which makes little sense for a text file parser.

Answer (score 3):

Try my java m3u parser:

Usage:

```
try{
 M3U_Parser mpt = new M3U_Parser();
 M3UHolder m3hodler = mpt.parseFile(new File("12397709.m3u"));
 for (int n = 0; n < m3hodler.getSize(); n++) {
 System.out.println(m3hodler.getName(n));
 System.out.println(m3hodler.getUrl(n));
 }
}catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace():
}
```

The project is posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/java-m3u-file-parser/)

Answer (score 2):

m3u is a regular text file that can be read line by line. Just remember the lines that start with # are comments. Here is a class I made for this very purpose. This class assumes you want only the files on the computer. If you want files on websites you will have to make some minor edits.

```
/*
 * Written by Edward John Sheehan III
 * Used with Permission
 */

package AppPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Edward John Sheehan III
 */
public class PlayList {
    List<String> mp3;
    int next;
    public PlayList(File f){
        mp3=new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               addMP3(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("error is reading the file");
        }
        next=-1;
    }    

    private void addMP3(String line){
        if(line==null)return;
        if(!Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(0)))return;
        if(line.indexOf(":\\")!=1)return;
        if(line.indexOf(".mp3", line.length()-4)==-1)return;
        mp3.add(line);
    }

    public String getNext(){
        next++;
        if(mp3.size()<=next)next=0;
        return mp3.get(next);
    }
}
```

Then just call

```
Playlist = new PlayList(file);
```